# How to distinguish if a plugin is not installed or just not active

Tags: plugins, php

I try to apply a check figuring out if a plugin is either not active or just not installed at all in the plugin directory. When I test I check for a plugin installed but not activated as seen in the screenshot.

[image: VSCode screen showing sidebar with the installed plugin and the editor screen with the code from underneath in the question]

The checking if inactive part works flawlessly:

```
$isinactive = is_plugin_inactive( 'advanced-custom-fields/acf.php' );
var_dump( $isinactive );
```

While checking if the plugin is actually installed and present in the plugin directory does not. First I generate the path to the main plugin file:

```
$pathpluginurl = plugins_url( 'advanced-custom-fields/acf.php' );
var_dump($pathpluginurl);
```

Then check if that file exists:

```
$isinstalled = file_exists( $pathpluginurl );
var_dump($isinstalled);
```

And then check if the particular file does NOT exist:

```
if ( ! file_exists( $pathpluginurl ) ) {
    echo "File does not exist";
} else {
    echo "File exists";
}
```

The output:

```
true //true for that the plugin is not active
http://mysandbox.test/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/acf.php
false  // false for that the acf.php file actually exists

file not exists
```

I don't understand why file_exists is not stating the facts and states the contrary saying the plugin does not exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`file_exists` expects a *path*, not a URL. To get the path to an arbitrary plugin you'll need to use `WP_PLUGIN_DIR`:

```
$pathpluginurl = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/advanced-custom-fields/acf.php';

$isinstalled = file_exists( $pathpluginurl );
```

Comment: ahhhhh that way it works! Thanks! But one question is there an alternative way aside using that constant? Because when you check https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories it is recommended not to use those constants directly in plugins and themes? :/

Comment: No, there isn't. Probably because generally you shouldn't be messing about in other plugins' directories. What are you ultimately trying to achieve here?

Comment: I don't wanted to mess with the other plugins' directory. ;) I just wanted to check its state. Meaning based on the state in case of not installed as well as installed but inactive i wanted to display different admin notices with generated links for installing advanced custom fields or just activating it.

Comment: `$pathpluginurl = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/advanced-custom-fields/acf.php'; if ( file_exists( $pathpluginurl )) { ...` also works too.

Answer (score 0):

you are using file_exists() function on an URL not on path to file, this will not work (in most cases).

Instead of

`$pathpluginurl = plugins_url( 'advanced-custom-fields/acf.php' );`

you should do to get an absolute file path

`$pathpluginurl = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/acf.php';`

Comment: The content directory can be changed. You shouldn't hard-code a specific path for it.